# JavaScript failed to load resource: file not found, but the file is a Laravel auto-generated view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

This is a problem that I just now encountered. When I go to certain pages within my application, I see an error in the dev console that says:

```
inject.preload.js:373 GET blob:http://my-app-name.test/ba65127c-383e-45b7-8159-9b52ea288658 0 ()
```

So, when I go to `inject.preloader.js`, and I find the line that is throwing the error, it says `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

That's fine. I know how to normally fix that error. But since I'm working with laravel for the first time, I believe that the file it's talking about is one of the files Laravel automatically generates in `App/storage/frameworks/views/`. And if that's the case, how do I fix this error?

The error doesn't actually impact anything. The pages it appears on are all functioning normally as far as I can tell, and there don't seem to be any issues in the blade files.

I was just curious if anyone else had encountered an issue like this before. I haven't changed my blade template used for the headers and scripts, and the only thing I changed in the page that is throwing the error is adding a bootstrap 4 modal.

I can link to a github repo if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this fixed it, but I moved my javascripts includes in the `master.blade.php` template, and it's not a problem anymore.